# Unexpected Token with Google API and Node.js

Tags: node.js, json, angular, api, google-oauth

I have the below method that uses @types/google-tap to authenticate via google. Below is my client code:`

```
LoginWithGoogle(credentials: string): Observable<any> {
    console.warn('it broke here')
    const header = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-type', 'application/json');
    return this.httpClient.post(this.path + "/loginwithgoogle", JSON.stringify(credentials), { headers: header });
  }
}`
```

Then I have the server which is on node.js:

```
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyparser.json());
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded())

app.post('/loginwithgoogle', function (req, response) {

    const decode = jwt.verify(req.body.token, 'secret here');

    res.json({
        login: true,
        data: decode
    });
});
```

When the api is called, I get the below error:

SyntaxError: Unexpected token " in JSON at position 0
at JSON.parse ()
at createStrictSyntaxError (C:\Repo\Sites\voyazair\voyazair\server\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:160:10)
at parse (C:\Repo\Sites\voyazair\voyazair\server\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:83:15)
at C:\Repo\Sites\voyazair\voyazair\server\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:128:18

Any Idea what I am doing wrong? I looked up for some solution that suggested JSON.Parse/JSON.stringify but that did not work for me.

Comment: do you have any logging in the node.js server app that you can check?
most likely the server app is throwing an exception and it might be as simple as changing the res.json to response.json on the node.js server app

Comment: it's failing when I am trying to log the request itself

Comment: My mistake, you are not sending json data to the server but just a plain string. Even though it is stringified you still need it to be a json object to start with.
Try changing JSON.stringify(credentials) to JSON.stringify({token:credentials})